# PythonでGoogle Driveにフォルダごとでアップロードしたい

Tags: python, python3, pydrive

pythonでローカルにあるフォルダをGoogle Driveにアップロードしたいです。
ローカルで作成した**uploadのフォルダ**をGoogle driveにアップしたいです。

**フォルダの階層**

```
フォルダ１階層
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\

アップロードしたいフォルダ
フォルダ名：upload
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload

※uploadのフォルダには
フォルダ・ファイルの階層まだあります。
uploadの中にある全てのフォルダ・ファイルをアップロードしたいです。

C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\test.txt

C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\upload2
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\upload2\test.txt

C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\upload2\uplpad3
C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test\upload\upload2\uplpad3\test.txt
```

下記のスクリプトで行いましたが、フォルダごとでアップロードできないです。
ファイルのみであればアップロードできます。

フォルダごとでアップロードすると下記のアクセス権限のエラーが表示されます。
もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。
また他の方法で自動アップロードする方法がありますでしょうか。

エラー内容

```
GoogleDriveFile({'parents': [{'id': '1J8TXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}], 'title': 'upload'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\googledrive_file_up.py", line 43, in <module>
    f.SetContentFile(os.path.join(path,x))
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pydrive\files.py", line 169, in SetContentFile
    self.content = open(filename, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\google drvie\\test\\upload'
```

参考ページ
[Python, PyDriveでGoogle Driveのフォルダ作成、ファイル移動、一括処理](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pydrive-folder/)

[PythonでGoogle Driveにファイルをアップロードする](https://laboratory.kazuuu.net/upload-files-to-google-drive-with-python/)

コード

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

import os

#Googleサービスを認証
gauth = GoogleAuth()

#資格情報ロードするか、存在しない場合は空の資格情報を作成
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")

#Googleサービスの資格情報がない場合
if gauth.credentials is None:
    #ユーザーから認証コードを自動的に受信しローカルWebサーバーを設定
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
#アクセストークンが存在しないか、期限切れかの場合    
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    #Googleサービスを認証をリフレッシュする
    gauth.Refresh()
#どちらにも一致しない場合    
else:
    #Googleサービスを承認する
    gauth.Authorize()
#資格情報をtxt形式でファイルに保存する  
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt") 
       
#Googleドライブの認証処理
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

#アップロードするフォルダパス指定
path = r'C:\Users\test\Documents\google drvie\test'
#GOOGLE DRIVEにUPするファイルID
folder_id='1J8TXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
#for文によるループ処理（繰り返し処理）
for x in os.listdir(path):
    #GoogleDriveFileオブジェクト作成
    #f = drive.CreateFile({'title' : x})
    f = drive.CreateFile({"parents": [{"id": folder_id},]})
    #ファイルのタイトル
    f['title'] = x
    #ローカルのファイルをセットしてアップロード
    print(f)
    f.SetContentFile(os.path.join(path,x))
    print(f)
    #Googleドライブにアップロード
    f.Upload()
    print(f)

    f = None
```

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

恐らく Google Drive API には「フォルダのアップロード」を行う機能が備わっていません。

そのため、(複数の階層を含む) フォルダをアップロードしたい場合には、自前で以下のような流れでの対応が必要になってきます。

- ローカルのファイル一覧を取得
- Google Drive 上にフォルダが存在するかチェックし、必要に応じて作成
- 指定のフォルダにアップロード

長くなるので引用は控えますが、例えば以下の記事の内容が参考になるかと思います。

**参考:**
[pyDriveを使ってGoogle Driveにフォルダをアップロード](https://northshorequantum.com/archives/pydrive_upload)

Comment: 参考ページの方法でファイルごとアップロードできました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

[colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) を使う方法

まずあらかじめ対象の複数のファイルをアーカイブしておく
(zip でも tar でも, どちらでも可)

colab の左サイドの「ファイル」から

1. アーカイブしておいた zip tar などをアップロード
2. ドライブをマウント
3. あとはセルを用意し展開

展開は, colabのセルを用意し, 以下のように(どちらか) 実行

```py
!unzip ZIPFILE.zip -d /content/drive/MyDrive/

!tar xf TARFILE.tar -C /content/drive/MyDrive/
```

---

定期的なアップロードの場合は

- HTTPサーバーを用意し, ファイル取得可能にしておく
- Colab Pro を検討する

以下サンプル, 適当。(マウントの認証は自動化できない)

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

for _ in range(10):
    # HTTPサーバーからファイル取得
    !wget ...
 
    # 展開
    !unzip
    # もしくは zipfile モジュール使って展開

    time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法も参考致します。